# skip encryption of the android device on enrollment (android management api)

Tags: android, api, encryption

I'm trying to enroll a device with the Android Device Policy app. I created a enrollment token, and typed it into the app. The app says it's going to encrypt the device. I want to skip the encryption, but it is not allowed. Is there any solution for that? Why is it mandatory to encrypt the device?

Edit:
The device is a Lollipop(Android 5.1) one. There is no camera or NFC on it.

Comment: I want to enroll my device with the Android Device Management API. I wrote how i tried to do that.

Comment: so, instead of `Android Device Policy app` it should be `Android Device Policy api` ?

Comment: There is an app which does it for the devices with 5.1 (it is not needed from 6).